# redcarpet-2.2.2 doesn't come the content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, redcarpet

Ruby: 2.0.0p0 , Rails: 3.2.13，redcarpet: 2.2.2
`application_helper.rb`

```
def markdown(text)                                                                                                     
markdown_render = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(:hard_wrap => true, :no_styles => true)
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(markdown_render, :autolink => true, :no_intro_emphasis => true) 
markdown.render(text).to_html.html_safe   
end
```

`app/views/questions/new.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for @question do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title, :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %> 
<%= markdown(@question.content) %> 
<%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %> 
<%= link_to 'Cancel', @question.id.blank? ? questions_path : question_path(params[:question]), :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

But it comes error:`wrong argument type nil (expected String)`, then i changed `<%= markdown(@question.content) %>` to `<%= markdown(@question.content.to_s) %>`, it then comes this error: `undefined methodto_html' for "":String`, so i changed `markdown.render(text).to_html.html_safe` to `markdown.render(text).html_safe` in the `application_help.rb` and it just has the title input field, the content input field has missed.
How can i fix this problem and if you need more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following helper:

```
def markdown(text)
  if text.blank?
    nil
  else
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true)
    markdown.render(text)
  end   
end
```

Comment: I'm not a Redcarpet user. I have to guess. Please try the new version I just edited. You don't seem to need the to_html part.

Comment: yes，you are right. I have removed the to_html part and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Rails 4.1.0.

Put the following in app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
def markdown(text)
if text.blank?
  nil
else
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true, filter_html:     true, hard_wrap: true, link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank" }, space_after_headers: true, fenced_code_blocks: true, superscript: true, disable_indented_code_blocks: true)
  markdown.render(text).html_safe
  end   
end
```

Think the only difference is putting `.html_safe` towards the end